# Two form elements on the same line?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have two elements on the same line?(Tight fit)
I set one to use 80% width, and the other to use 20%, but it won't fit in the space?

This is what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/NuZxj/

I thought this would be possible, but I'm very new to HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of two things; first: the `width` property doesn't set the 'total width' of the element, the total width is comprised of the width, plus the border-width plus the padding.

Secondly the line-break between the two elements in the HTML will be rendered as a single white-space character, so the 20% plus the 80% would add up to over 100% anyway.

That said, if you place the two elements on the same line in the HTML and use the following `box-sizing` then the border-width and padding are included within the `width` of the element, as set via CSS (IE, I believe, calculates `width` this way by default):

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NuZxj/11/).

Note, also, that the HTML has been changed so that there's no space, of any kind, between the two `input` elements.

Comment: `box-sizing` is one solution which will work (basically, it simplifies the box model), but keep in mind it has limited support. It is, to my knowledge, not how IE calclulates it by default — are you sure about this?

It's quite possible to make it work without the `box-sizing`.

Comment: It's something that's stuck in my head for some reason. It may have been an old artefact of an old version of IE that had me convinced, though.

Comment: Such a great answer, thanks to everyone. Could you point me in the right direction for learning CSS? You're clearly very good at it. Thanks.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually does what I need, i tried floating them, but I just needed to remove that gap. Thanks

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped! As for learning CSS? I'd suggest reading [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/), [Eric Meyer's blog](http://meyerweb.com/), and exploring [CSS Play](http://cssplay.co.uk/). There are so many others to look at, though, it's a huge field. Good luck! =)

Answer (score 1):

The elements have a border which prevents them from being on the same line as it adds to their width. Set that to 0 and make them float left. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NuZxj/10/)

```
#footer input[type=text]
{
    border: 0;
    float: left;
}

input.button {
    border: 0;
    float: left;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/NuZxj/13/

Add `float: right;` to the button to force it to the right side of the div, this will put both elements on the same line. This of course will not look correct if you don't want it on the right side.

Do note I also changed the width of the text element to slightly less than 80% so it would fit on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/NuZxj/7/

The thing about HTML elements though, it that you can't always depend on `width` alone, since there are some things that add to the actual space the elements take up, such as `margin` and `border`. This is called the "box model", and you can read about it here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html or here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

What it means in your example, is that the `width` do take up 100%, leaving no room for the border on the button, for example — which is why the button jumps down on the next line.

You can either remove the `border`, `padding` and `margin`, or tweak the `width` of the two elements.

Answer (score 0):

The two elements won't fit onto the same line because there is padding and/or a margin defined.

This means that `80% + 20% + margin + padding + border > 100%`.

The width property does not take the margin, padding, or border into consideration.

To get around this, you either want to set the margin, padding, and border to `0px`, reduce the percentage width a tiny amount to compensate, or (the most complex option) wrap the inputs in an invisible div and set the width of that instead.